# Desktop flicker and not responsive, reduced resolution is OK

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution

I run Ubuntu 20.04 for quite a while on a Intel CPU with integrated graphics on a Monitor with fullHD ( resolution to 1920x1080). Recently the desktop became unresponsive (sometimes turns black). Starting any program crashes the desktop sending me back to the login screen. Running the system in recovery mode (1024x768) works flawlessly. The monitor is proven ok (parallel windows). I did no changes on the system on purpose. How can I find the problem? How can I repair it?
Kernel: 5.8.0-36 and -40, it happens on both
update:
BTW installed xfce and it runs fine.

Comment: Just tested: Starting any program crashes the desktop sending me back to the login screen.

Comment: That comment belongs in the question. What kernel version are you running and do you know if there was a recent software upgrade?

Comment: @David: see edits in Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Gnome failed.
Reinstalling entire system failed (same result).
good bye ubuntu
Installed Mint Linux - runs flawlessly.